# Linux x64: why does r10 come before r8 and r9 in syscalls?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, calling-convention

I decided to take a crack at assembly the other day, and I've been playing around with really basic things like printing stuff from argv to stdout. I found [this great list of linux syscall numbers](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) with arguments and everything, and I'm curious why `r10` is used for arguments before `r8` and `r9`. I've found all kinds of weird conventions about what can be used what for what and when, like how loop counters go in `rcx`. Is there a particular reason why `r10` was moved up? Was it more convenient?

I should probably also mention I'm interested in this out of curiosity, not because it's causing me problems.

Edit: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/849185) which gets close, referencing [the x64 ABI documentation](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) on page 124, where it notes that user level applications use `rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9`. The kernel on the other hand uses `r10` instead of `rcx`, and destroys `rcx` and `r11`. That might explain how `r10` ended up there, but then why was it swapped in?

Comment: Because [Why do x86-64 Linux system calls modify RCX, and what does the value mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47983371).  Just replacing RCX with R10 allows a single `mov r10,rcx` ; `syscall` in libc wrapper functions.  [Why Assembly x86\_64 syscall parameters are not in alphabetical order like i386](//stackoverflow.com/q/47676657)

Answer (score 10):

`RCX`, along with `R11`, is used by the `syscall` instruction, being immediately destroyed by it. Thus these registers are not only not saved after syscall, but they can't even be used for parameter passing. Thus `R10` was chosen to replace unusable `RCX` to pass fourth parameter.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32480482/673852) for a bit more information on how `syscall` uses these registers.

Reference: [Intel's Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf), look for `SYSCALL`.

Comment: The other option would have been for syscall args to go in `rdi, rsi, rdx, r8, r9, r10`, but that has more args in different regs vs. the user-space convention.  With the actual design Linux chose, with R10 taking the place of RCX, a libc wrapper function may be as simple as `mov r10, rcx` / `syscall` / `ret`, instead of needing to copy 3 registers.

Answer (score 2):

see [x86-64.orgs abi documentation](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) `page 124`

> 1. User-level applications use as integer registers for passing the sequence
>      %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9. The kernel interface uses %rdi,
>      %rsi, %rdx, %r10, %r8 and %r9.
> 2. A system-call is done via the syscall instruction. The kernel destroys
>      registers %rcx and %r11.

This is saying that when you use the syscall instruction the kernel destroys `%rcx` so you need to use `%r10` instead.

---

Also the comment from @technosaurus explains that the kernel is using `%rcx` to store the *entry point* in case of an interrupt during a syscall.

Comment: Is this referring to syscalls? With `mmap` for example, you pass flags in `r10`, and flags are not a static chain pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure.. i'm confused now, i think (i thought) it was used behind the scenes to calculate the addresses of the arguments on the stack, on page 123 _Linux Conventions_ it says "The Linux AMD64 kernel uses internally the same calling conventions as user-level applications (see section 3.2.3 for details)" - _(the beginning of the section i pointed you to??)_

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/849185) which gets close, referencing the same document on page 124, where it notes that user level applications use `rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9`. The kernel on the other hand uses `r10` instead of `rcx`, and destroys `rcx` and `r11`. That might explain how `r10` ended up there, but then why was it swapped in?

Comment: 124 - not that it's swapped for the destroyed `rcx`, but rather that the kernel does not accept an argument in `rcx`, the fourth argument is stored in `r10` instead, and when the syscall returns `rcx` is destroyed. (at least as I understand it)

Comment: According to ftp://ftp.csc.fi/pub/Linux/kernel/v2.4/patch-html/patch-2.4.20/linux-2.4.20_arch_x86_64_kernel_entry.S.html it looks like rcx is used by the kernel to store the entry point in case of an interrupt, but for convenience r10 is copied to rcx on return, so a simple mov from rcx to r10 before the syscall should suffice.

Comment: @technosaurus ahh thanks for the information, i think i'd completely missed the point and misunderstood everything, i should probably edit my answer to at least answer the question, seems OP was right on the money with referencing page 124 and I don't know what I was on about.

Comment: I never did track down exactly why rcx was used to save the entry point instead of r10... Maybe it's the last one guaranteed not to be clobbered by interrupts... Pure speculation

Comment: @technosaurus The `syscall` instruction *itself* destroys RCX (and R11).  AMD designed it that way.  GCC devs still chose RCX for the user-space calling convention to save code size (avoid REX prefixes).  [Why do x86-64 Linux system calls modify RCX, and what does the value mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47983371)

Comment: [What's the best way to remember the x86-64 System V arg register order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63891991) has some discussion of that design decision.