# Why do x86-64 Linux system calls modify RCX, and what does the value mean?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I'm trying to allocate some memory in linux with `sys_brk` syscall. Here is what I tried:

```
BYTES_TO_ALLOCATE equ 0x08

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 12
    mov rdi, BYTES_TO_ALLOCATE
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

The thing is as per linux calling convention I expected the return value to be in `rax` register (pointer to the allocated memory). I ran this in gdb and after making `sys_brk` syscall I noticed the following register contents

Before syscall

```
rax            0xc      12
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x0      0
rdx            0x0      0
rsi            0x0      0
rdi            0x8      8
```

After syscall

```
rax            0x401000 4198400
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x40008c 4194444 ; <---- What does this value mean?
rdx            0x0      0
rsi            0x0      0
rdi            0x8      8
```

I do not quite understand the value in the `rcx` register in this case. Which one to use as a pointer to the beginning of 8 bytes I allocated with `sys_brk`?

Comment: RCX and R11 are clobbered by the [SYSCALL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) instruction itself. From the instruction set reference: _after saving the address of the instruction following SYSCALL into RCX)_. _RFLAGS_ gets stored into _R11_

Comment: @MichaelPetch Very interesting. It means in order to use, say `cl` register afterwards I need to clear it first, right? I mean for example `xor cl, cl` and then `mov cl, 7`.

Comment: You can't rely on the value of _RCX_ or _R11_ after the SYSCALL. So you'll have to either use one of the other registers instead of _RCX_ and _R11_ (and RAX) or you will have to save the value (stack for example) and restore it after. _RCX_ and _R11_ don't get set by you, you just can't use them and expect them to be the same before and after the SYSCALL.

Comment: @MichaelPetch But what's wrong with just clearing?

Comment: Clearing it before will get overwritten by the SYSCALL. SYSCALL will just overwrite what was in it. You can set it after the SYSCALL if you wish but if you do another SYSCALL the value will be clobbered.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The system call return value is in `rax`, as always.  See [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6).

Note that `sys_brk` has a slightly different interface than the `brk` / `sbrk` POSIX functions; see the [C library/kernel differences section of the Linux `brk(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html).  Specifically, **Linux `sys_brk` *sets* the program break**; the arg and return value are both pointers.  See [Assembly x86 brk() call use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586532/assembly-x86-brk-call-use/44876873#44876873).  That answer needs upvotes because it's the only good one on that question.

---

The other interesting part of your question is:

> I do not quite understand the value in the rcx register in this case

You're seeing the mechanics of how the [`syscall`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/SYSCALL) / [`sysret`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/SYSRET) instructions are designed to allow the kernel to resume user-space execution but still be fast.

`syscall` doesn't do any loads or stores, it only modifies registers.  Instead of using special registers to save a return address, it simply uses regular integer registers.

**It's not a coincidence that `RCX=RIP` and `R11=RFLAGS` after the kernel returns to your user-space code**.  The only way for this *not* to be the case is if a `ptrace` system call modified the process's saved `rcx` or `r11` value while it was inside the kernel. (`ptrace` is the system call gdb uses).  In that case, Linux would use `iret` instead of `sysret` to return to user space, because the slower general-case `iret` can do that.  (See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code/46087731#46087731) for some walk-through of Linux's system-call entry points.  Mostly the entry points from 32-bit processes, not from `syscall` in a 64-bit process, though.)

---

Instead of pushing a return address onto the kernel stack (like `int 0x80` does), **`syscall`**:

- sets RCX=RIP, R11=RFLAGS   (so it's impossible for the kernel to even see the original values of those regs before you executed `syscall`).
- masks `RFLAGS` with a pre-configured mask from a config register (the `IA32_FMASK` MSR).  This lets the kernel disable interrupts (IF) until it's done `swapgs` and setting `rsp` to point to the kernel stack.  Even with `cli` as the first instruction at the entry point, there'd be a window of vulnerability.  You also get `cld` for free by masking off `DF` so `rep movs` / `stos` go upward even if user-space had used `std`.

  Fun fact: AMD's first proposed `syscall` / `swapgs` design didn't mask RFLAGS, but [they changed it after feedback from kernel developers on the amd64 mailing list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528) (in ~2000, a couple years before the first silicon).
- jumps to the configured `syscall` entry point (setting CS:RIP = `IA32_LSTAR`).  The old `CS` value isn't saved anywhere, I think.
- It doesn't do anything else, the kernel has to use `swapgs` to get access to an info block where it saved the kernel stack pointer, because `rsp` still has its value from user-space.

So the design of `syscall` requires a system-call ABI that clobbers registers, and that's why the values are what they are.

Comment: What is the use case of `sysret` instruction? Link you provided mentions that, it is companion instruction for `syscall`. But I have never seen `sysret` being used after a `syscall` instruction!!

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: `syscall` calls into the kernel, `sysret` (in the kernel) returns to user-space.  So the reason is the same as why you don't use `ret` after `call printf`, unless that happens to be the end of your function.  See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) for some details about how the kernel int 0x80 and syscall entry points work.

Comment: If saved `RCX != RIP` or `R11 != RFLAGS`, linux kernel uses `iret` instead of `sysret`. Why not just restore `%rcx/%r11` with saved `RIP/RFLAGS` and use `sysret` (I think this will be faster?)

Comment: @FangZhen: Because of CPU / ISA design bugs.  e.g. if RIP is non-canonical, the CPU will #GP.  But Intel CPUs will handle that exception without updating RSP (so it's the user stack), but the CPU is still in kernel mode.  User-space could easily exploit that by having another thread modify that memory which is getting used as a kernel stack, after using ptrace to create a non-canonical RIP.  So some checking is needed, and since `ptrace` or signals changing registers of other tasks are rare, it's fastest to just use a simple check.

Comment: @FangZhen: See https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L260 for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes As for the linked code, what happens if replace line 255-258 with following which avoids check `RCX==RIP`?
`
movq    RIP(%rsp), %rcx  \n
movq    %rcx, %r11
`

Comment: @FangZhen: That would lead to wrong behaviour for cases where ptrace wanted to set RCX in another task. (Or maybe a signal handler modifying registers).  e.g. in GDB, `set $rcx = 1` is something that's supposed to work, but your change would break it.  (Maybe just for tasks that were stuck in a system call, or maybe for any task even if it was stopped at a breakpoint if that return path gets used there.)